# Count the number of occurrences within a Dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Python Dataframe with a column called points.

```
Points
20
5000
1
30
20
```

I want to count the number of values within a certain range, lets say between 10 and 100, which should return 3 in this case. How do I do that in Python? 
I know I can use `(df["Points"] == 20).sum()`  to return the count of values = 20 which will give 2 in this case, but I don't know how to do it for a range of values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution:

```
len(df.query("10 < Points < 100"))
```